# Could you help me with a problem displaying matrix?

Tags: c++

(Thank you all that helped me so fast, but i didn't resolve my problem, i re-edited my post to be more specific)

I want to create a 10x10 matrix to store 10 rows of char value from 'a' to 'j'.

I'm having trouble displaying a matrix 10x10. Can someone explain me why?
Here the code:

This function puts letters a to j in every row

```
void inizializza_tab(char tab[][9]){ //Carica con ~ le tabelle
for(int x=0;x<=9;x++)
{
    for(int y=0;y<=9;y++){
        tab[x][y]=y+97;  //Tabella ASCII, onde del mare;
    }
}}
```

This function prints matrix on display

```
void stampatab(char tab[][9]){
cout<<"        ";
for(char d='A';d<='J';d++){     //Dispone le lettere da A a J
    cout<<d<<"  ";
}
cout<<endl;
for(int r=0;r<=9;r++)
{
    cout<<"\n     "<<r+1<<"  ";//Dispone in colonna i numeri da 1 a 10 
    for(int c=0 ;c<=9 ;c++){
        cout<<tab[r][c]<<"  ";  //Spazio fra le onde del mare;
    }
    cout<<endl<<endl;
}}
```

The output should be:

```
      A B C D E F G H I J
   1  a b c d e f g h i j 
   2  a b c d e f g h i j 
   3  a b c d e f g h i j 
   4  a b c d e f g h i j 
   5  a b c d e f g h i j 
   6  a b c d e f g h i j 
   7  a b c d e f g h i j 
   8  a b c d e f g h i j 
   9  a b c d e f g h i j 
  10  a b c d e f g h i j
```

but actually the output is:

```
      A B C D E F G H I J
   1  a b c d e f g h i a //wrong
   2  a b c d e f g h i a //wrong
   3  a b c d e f g h i a //wrong
   4  a b c d e f g h i a //wrong
   5  a b c d e f g h i a //wrong
   6  a b c d e f g h i a //wrong
   7  a b c d e f g h i a //wrong
   8  a b c d e f g h i a //wrong
   9  a b c d e f g h i a //wrong
  10  a b c d e f g h i j //correct
```

Comment: Prefer to use character literals, such as 'A' than ASCII or Unicode encoding values.

Comment: You don't need to convert character to `int` to use in `for` loop.  Try this:  `for (char lett = 'A'; lett <= 'Z'; ++lett)`.

Comment: For a 9x9-matrix the indices must be `0 <= i < 9` but you have multiple loops where the indices can reach 9, which is out of bounds.

Comment: @churill has right, If the matrix is 9x9 your for have to go from 0 to 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the matrix is 10x10 you have to start the for from 0 to 10(not included).
Read [Documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/).
I also changed the For loops with the char value how suggested by @ThomasMatthews

```
    void inizializza_tab(char tab[][10]){ //Carica con ~ le tabelle
    for(int x=0;x<10;x++)
    {
        for(int y=0;y<10;y++){
            tab[x][y]=y+97;  //Tabella ASCII, onde del mare;
        }
    }
  }
  void stampatab(char tab[][10]){
    char lett;
    cout<<"        ";
    for(char d='A';d<='J';d++){     //Dispone le lettere da A a J

        cout<<d<<"  ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    for(int r=0;r<10;r++)
    {
        cout<<"\n     "<<r+1<<"  ";//Dispone in colonna i numeri da 1 a 10
        for(int c=0 ;c<10;c++){
            cout<<tab[r][c]<<"  ";  //Spazio fra le onde del mare;
        }
        cout<<endl<<endl;
    }
  }
```

Comment: how fast! thank you but i have same problem. In my post i will be more specific

Comment: So you want a 10x10 matrix. I edited the code. If it works consider to accept my answer :)

Comment: No, it didn't. Always in rows 1 to 9 it ends with "a". Only the last one rows is correct that display letters from "a" to "j"

Comment: Try now, i've posted the wrong code but now I've corrected

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. Now it works. Can i ask you another queastion about this? Now matrix is 11x11 i need a real matrix 10x10 (100 boxes), should i leave the code as you wrote? Why it work so `char tab[10][10]` and not so `char tab[9][9]`?

Comment: Now the Matrix is 10x10(100 boxes) and your for go from 0 to 10(not included). If you want a 11X11(121 boxes) your for go from 0 to 11(not included).

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong: i remember that if index of array is for example 4 (`char tab[4]`) c++ stores 5 boxes for variables 0 included to 4 included

Comment: No, the number between the [] is the dimension of the array, for example v[4] is an array of 4 "boxes", from 0 to 3. Read the documentation that I linked in the answer

Comment: Ah it's true. ahahhahaha sorry for all this question.Thank you so much above all for patience! Forgive me i'm trying to write battle ship in c++ after 3 year without programming! i'm 18 in a scientific high school in Italy, so try to imagine how little the teacher explained to me. =)

Comment: I'm too 18 in scientific high school(scienze applicate) in Italy :).Good luck! Some profs explain very little :(.If you have done please accept my answer :).